# Suppress "The resource name is not a valid identifier"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, embedded-resource

I have a project with 5000+ resource strings in it. Almost all of them have periods in their identifier.

We're switching over to automatically generating strongly-typed classes, and of course, because of the periods, we see a few thousand warnings

> The resource name 'blah' is not a valid identifier.

I know it isn't, the generator changes periods to underscores, and everything is fine.

Can I suppress the warning? It doesn't seem to have an associated number to #pragma away.

Comment: The answer is "no". And since we cannot change the keys (our localization hangs off of it), I'm pretty much stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I can repro, although it isn't crystal in the question.  Project + Properties, Resources and type a string resource name like "foo.bar" triggers this warning.

Yes, you cannot suppress this warning, it is generated by the resource designer in the IDE.  When it auto-generates the code from the Properties\Resources.resx file to the Properties\Resources.Designer.cs file.  Look at the .resx file and check the "name" attribute on the `<data>` elements.  A period in the attribute value is going to trigger the warning.

A carefully crafted search-and-replace with regexp could fix that by turning the periods into underscores.  That gives me personally two problems, I'd just write a little program that uses XDocument.  Also check if you still need this auto-generated code, sounds like you are replacing it.

Comment: No, we're moving from manual reflection to auto-generated classes. Just renaming won't work since we have an entire i18n toolchain that keys off these identifiers. Sigh...

Comment: That doesn't help me help you.  The warning being generated by the resource designer is still my favorite explanation.

Comment: Should've been more clear, I guess. Unless someone comes up with a workaround I'll give you the bounty anyways.

Answer (score 2):

This will suppress all warnings for a given .cs file with

```
#pragma warning disable
```

You should also be able to right click on the warning and then click on the Show Error Help.  It should give the exact warning number so that you can suppress just that warning for the entire project by going into the project properties, then the build page and entering it into the Suppress Warnings textbox.

After further research  it appears that some warnings can not be suppressed.  See the details on msdn about the /nowarn C# Compiler options http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f28x9z3.aspx

One of them is the Compiler Warning (level 1) CS2029 which refers to the "is not a valid identifier" warning you are getting.  You can further confirm that it cannot be suppressed by visiting the details on the Compiler Warning (level1) CS2029 here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/878y1894.aspx

Comment: The .cs files are automatically generated. There is no warning number.

Comment: It's not 2029. There is no number. /W0 has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

A REALLY awful work-around here would be to de-couple the generated code from the Resource tool:

Let's say your resource file's name is **Resources.resx**

1. Open the resource tool by double clicking the Resources.resx in the project inside Visual Studio.
2. Set your Access modifier appropriate to the generated code scope you are using.
3. In Windows explorer, go to the directory housing your **Resources.resx** and **Resources.Designer.cs** code.  (Either manually browsing or right clicking on your project/namespace folder and selecting "Open Folder in Windows Explorer")
4. Rename **Resources.Designer.cs** to **Resources.cs**
5. Go back to the resource tool in Visual Studio and set the Access modifier to "No code generation"
6. Save, close the resource tool
7. Click the "Show All Files" icon at the top of the solution explorer window.  The **Resources.cs** file should appear in the same folder as **Resources.resx** in ghosted form
8. Right click on **Resources.cs** and select "Include in Project"

The warnings should now disappear.  Of course, the inconvenience of this work around is that you will have to do all of these steps any time you modify the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs if the resource name is not a valid identifier (for example, it contains a space or '-'), and strongly typed resource generation is turned on for the file. This is a warning instead of an error because the strongly typed resource name will be changed to a valid name (for example, "a b" will be changed to "a_b"), but the resource name will remain "a b."

**To correct this error**

You should first change the name of the resource to a valid identifier, if possible. If that is not a valid option, disable strongly typed resource code generation for this .resx file. To do this, select the .resx file in Solution Explorer and clear the Custom Tool property.

SOURCE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228672(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: and what if I need code (.Designer.cs) and can't rename resource name at all..?? is there any other workaround..?